# Dual vector bundle in differential geometry

Tags: geometry

I am a graduate student in control theory. The entity "vector bundle" appears oftentimes. For instance, the tangent vector bundle $TM$ is the set of local tangent vector spaces at coordinate $x$ of a certain manifold $M$. It utilizes the "vector bundle" $\xi$ with total manifold $E_\xi$ (belonging to which I do not grasp) in the case of a fiber $\xi_p$, for coordinate $p \in M$ and a section $\Gamma(\xi)$, as the name recalls, the applications around the neighborhood of certain coordinate $p$ belonging to fiber $\xi_p$.

I do not comprehend, however, what a dual vector bundle means. The article available on [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/mana.19680380302) on page 140, says the following, in german:

Let application $X \in \Gamma(TM)$ and $s \in \Gamma_p(\xi)$. Then, for each vector $v \in T_p M$, there is an element $\nabla_v s \in \xi$ unequivocally defined by equality $\nabla_v s := (\nabla_X s)_p$, for $X_p = v$. Let $\xi^*$ be a $\xi$ dual vector bundle, so there is for each $\omega \in \Gamma_p(\xi^*)$ and each $v \in T_p M$ exactly one element $\nabla_v \omega \in \xi_p^*$ with:

$v \cdot \langle \omega, s \rangle = \langle \nabla_v \omega, s \rangle + \langle \omega, \nabla_v s \rangle$.

Comment: The dual bundle $\xi^*$ is the bundle where for each $p \in M$, the fiber $\xi^*_p$ is the dual vector space (in the usual linear algebra sense) to $\xi_p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total manifold of the bundle is just the underlying manifold to the vector bundle, forgetting the projection and the base.

If you assume for a second that your vector bundle $\xi$ as a sub-bundle of a trivial bundle $U\times M$ the total manifold of $\xi$ is just
$$\{ (v,p) \in U \times M \mid v \in \xi_p \}$$

The dual bundle to $\xi$ is the vector bundle deduced from $\xi$ by replacing each fibre $\xi_p$ by its dual $\xi'_p$, the vector space of linear forms on $\xi_p$. Other canonical constructions made “fibre by fibre” yield more fibre bundles: taking cartesian products, symmetric or exterior powers, or looking for the zero hyperplan of a linear form, for instance.

A difficulty to begin in this topic is that the “synthetic” approach used in the article summons a great many different notions. All of them are really needed, and in the end, it is much easier than the “coordinates” approach, since it allows to reason geometrically rather than to reduce everything to a coordinate computation.  If that helps, it is useful to translate “in coordinates” for a while — and that is most of the time mandatory to work out examples.

Suggested reads: Michael Spivak, Jacques Lafontaine (Introduction to differential Manifolds), but really speak with your professor before spending a long time in the books, so that they can help you to make an appropriate use of them, especially regarding the balance between understanding the vocabulary of differential geometry and bee-lining to the topic you are actually interested in.

Comment: I thank deerly (since you help me avoid bee-lining) for the explanation. I was advised to read Spivak as you mention, complementar to Burke and Manfredo Perdigão. If you are literate in german, I recommend the article.

Answer (score 0):

In the *standard basis* in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we have $\partial_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ (ith directional derivative/ coordinate vector), dually we have $\partial^i = dx^i$ (ith component function/ increment). They interact via natural pairing:
$$\partial^i(\partial_j) = \delta^i_j = \bigg\{\begin{matrix}1&&\text{ if i=j}\\0&&\text{otherwise}\end{matrix}.$$

---

For example:
Let $v = \partial_1+2\partial_2$ and suppose $\omega = -\partial^1+4\partial^2.$
Then:
$$\omega(v) = (-\partial^1+4\partial^2)(\partial_1+2\partial_2) = -\partial^1\partial_1 -2\partial^1\partial_2 +4\partial^2\partial_1+8\partial^2\partial_2 = -1 - 0 + 0 + 8 = 7.$$

---

Now, suppose $X\in \Gamma(TM)$ (i.e. $X$ is a vector field) and $\omega\in \Gamma(T^*M)$ (i.e. $\omega$ is a dual vector field), then at each point, $p\in M$ we have a chart $\varphi:U_p\to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the *pullback* of $\omega_p$ through the inverse and the *pushforward* of $X_p$ interact as in the above example (down in $\mathbb{R}^n$):
$$(\varphi^{-1})^*(\omega_p)\bigg(\varphi_*(X_p)\bigg).$$
Alternatively, if we induce coordinate frames on the bundles (or otherwise just have them from context), we may write out the interaction over the manifold itself: $\omega_p(X_p)$ and evaluate according to the kronecker-delta expression ($\delta^i_j$) between the frames.

---

This was in attempt to illustrate how duality works in basic differential geometry (involving tangent and cotangent vector bundles). The idea should be roughly the same for other vector bundles and their duals. I hope this edit helps!

Comment: You prefer a physics explanation, which in my and Grothendieck's opinion is careless and irresponsible to your reader's comprehension. I think you should read the answer I marked as the proper one.

Comment: This is what duality means in the linear algebraic sense at the level developed in charts. This is actually used to evaluate tensor and tensor field components. The excerpt includes covariant derivative identities, which are not necessary for understanding duality?

Comment: It seems an advanced topic, which I may stumble into later on. The concept presented as chosen answer suffices for me. I do not comprehend, however, what does pullback means. I will post another question.

Comment: I do thank you for answer improvement. I understand $\Gamma(\cdot)$ as the applications on certain vector bundle. You utilize, for instance, $X$ and $\omega$. What is your understanding about this geometrical concept?

Comment: The $\Gamma(\cdot)$ stands for “sections of ($\cdot$)”, where the variable is a vector bundle. Sections are fields essentially. They are poorly named imo. You take a point on the manifold and associate an object of type specified by the bundle. So for example: $”X:p\mapsto X_p”$ and $”\omega: p\mapsto \omega_p$” only technically speaking the pair is kept in the image: $p\mapsto (p,v)$. This makes the section/projection pair one sided inverses ($\sigma \circ \pi = Id_{VB}$). John Lee’s “Introduction to Smooth Manifolds” is a good text for this.

Comment: The book you mention is on its way to my home at this moment. Mind-reading is a richly named term for this phenomenon. According to the article from Dombrovski on original post, Sections are applications (maps) on elements of a vector bundle, oftentimes the tangent bundle.

Comment: @KevinS The $\Gamma(X)$ denotes *global sections* of $X$, it is also customary to denote local sections over an open space $U$ with $\Gamma(X,U)$. When $U$ is small enough so that the restriction of $X$ above $U$  is trivial, sections above $U$ are actually sections (or cross-sections) of the trivialisation. There is at least two reasons why they don't call them fields: First is that the name is already taken and used in a context where bundles and sections are pervasive (algebraic geometry). Second is that sections are not only for vector bundles but also for sheaves, fields are very remote.

Comment: @MichaëlLeBarbier $\v{C}$ontext should specify algebraic field vs. physical. It's a matter of opinion at this point, write whatever you feel comfortable with!

Comment: Yes, at one point it's a matter of convention between a speaker and their audience. Since it's a beginner's questions I wanted to explain the terminology “section” and how “field” collides with other important terminology, especially in a context where the two notions are used together.